# Maven gitflow fails with: release: fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories

Tags: maven, github-actions, git-flow

On github actions, am trying to release a version but it fails with error:

> release: fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories

Here is the command run:

```
mvn -B gitflow:release -DreleaseVersion=${{ github.event.inputs.releaseVersion }} -DdevelopmentVersion=${{ github.event.inputs.developmentVersion }}
```

Thanks